# Problem with Null Check Operator Being Called on a Null Value in a Use Case Involving Named Routing with Arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, null, navigation

**[PLEASE SEE EDIT BELOW]**

I am using named routing (with arguments) to send a user from page2 back to page1 in my app when a button is pressed:

```
onPressed: () {
  bool resumeProcess = true;
  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/',
      arguments: RouteArguments(resumeProcess: resumeProcess));
},
```

My named routing is set up in my [`MaterialApp`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final RouteArguments args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as RouteArguments;
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Reactive BLE Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(
              title: 'Reactive BLE Test',
              resumeProcess: args.resumeProcess,
            ),
        '/myWifiPage': (context) => const MyWifiPage(),
      },
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using the following class in conjunction with `ModalRoute` to retrieve `args.resumeProcess`:

```
class RouteArguments {
  final bool resumeProcess;

  RouteArguments({required this.resumeProcess});
}
```

and

```
final RouteArguments args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as RouteArguments;
```

I'm unable to retrieve `args.resumeProcess` because my bang operator is being used on a null value at runtime.

I have tried different ways to solve this problem with no success. There are some good posts about this, but none seem to fit my use case (or maybe I'm missing something).

Is there a better way to send these arguments, or is there a way to deal with this null problem at runtime?

***[BEGIN EDIT HERE]***

While trying to fix the problem above, I turned to the recipe for doing this provided in the Flutter Docs: [Pass arguments to a named route](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments). This resulted in the following changes.

**New ScreenArguments Class:**

```
class ScreenArguments {
  final String title;
  final String resumeProcess;

  ScreenArguments({required this.title, required this.resumeProcess});
}
```

**New ExtractArgumentsScreen Class**

```
class ExtractArgumentsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExtractArgumentsScreen({super.key});

  static const routeName = '/';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as ScreenArguments;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(args.resumeProcess),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My MaterialApp is located in MyApp. This is where I register the widget in the routes table per the docs. I've commented out the old routes.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Reactive BLE Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      // routes: {
      //   '/': (context) => MyHomePage(
      //         title: 'Reactive BLE Test',
      //         resumeProcess: args.resumeProcess,
      //       ),
      //   '/myWifiPage': (context) => const MyWifiPage(),
      // },
      routes: {
        ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName: (context) =>
            const ExtractArgumentsScreen(),
      },
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, I navigate to the widget in my second page (returning from page 2 to page 1) using `Navigator.pushNamed()`.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: const Text('Reactive BLE Test'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            String title = 'Reactive BLE Test';
            String resumeProcess = 'true';
            Navigator.pushNamed(
              context,
              ExtractArgumentsScreen.routeName,
              arguments: ScreenArguments(
                title: title,
                resumeProcess: resumeProcess,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: const [],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
```

I get a new, but similar error:

*type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'ScreenArguments' in type cast*

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling it on the wrong place. these `ModalRoute.of(context)` must be associated with context that having modal routes, or routes. in this case MaterialApp which hold the routes. But you are calling it before the MaterialApp is created. try to move it into inside of `MyHomePage` and read the arguments inside there instead of passing it as arguments on the material app Routes.

for example:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Reactive BLE Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => MyHomePage(
              title: 'Reactive BLE Test',
            ),
        '/myWifiPage': (context) => const MyWifiPage(),
      },
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    );
  }
```

and inside your `MyHomePage` widget:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final RouteArguments args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as RouteArguments;
    var resumeProcess = args.resumeProcess;
    return Scaffold(
        // your home page class
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @hayi-nukman. I tried using your recommendations, but I think my initial approach was totally wrong. I have edited my post to show my new code. It is largely derived from the Flutter Docs recipe for using this (link included). I'm getting a new null related error; 'type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'ScreenArguments' in type cast. I'm still not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Hi @MySilmaril I am seeing that your `ExtractArgumentsScreen` route is `/`, which also the initial routes on your MaterialApp `initialRoute: '/',`.
as you know, at initial these will call your `ExtractArgumentsScreen`  as the initial screen. if you mean these screen as 2nd page, then make the `initialRoute` value is opening the 1st page. For example: in routes add:
`'/first' : (_) => FirstPage(), '/second' : (_) => ExtractArgumentsScreen(),`
then set `initialRoute` to `'/first'`.

Comment: Thanks again @hayi-nukman. With your help, I was able to resolve this routing problem. In fact, I wrote a test app so I could focus on the recipe in the Flutter Docs. I am now able to route from `MyHomePage()` to `MyWifiPage()` with no issues. However, I also need to route back from `MyWifiPage()` to `MyHomePage()` and I'm not sure how to do that. Since this is a different problem, I have created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74006106/routing-question-pertaining-to-named-routing-with-arguments-using-modalroute-of). Any chance you can help me resolve this last issue?