# Routing Question Pertaining to Named Routing With Arguments Using ModalRoute.of()

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, arguments

I have written a small test app to explore named routing with arguments using `ModalRoute.of()` as explained in the [Flutter Docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments). My test app consists of an initial page (`MyFirstPage()`) and four additional pages (e.g. `MySecondPage()`, `MyThirdPage()`, etc.). Everything is working fine when I route from `MyFirstPage()` to any of these other pages.

However, I would like to add a button to `MySecondPage()` to route the user back to `MyFirstPage()` using the same recipe. When I try to do this, I get an error:

"type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FirstPageArguments' in type cast"

where `FirstPageArguments()` is a class that defines the arguments I'd like to pass in the route:

```
class FirstPageArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  FirstPageArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

My code follows ...

**MyFirstPage()**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'page2.dart';
import 'page3.dart';
import 'page4.dart';
import 'page5.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      //home: const MyFirstPage(title: 'Named Routes'),
      //initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // register the page widgets in the routes table
        MyFirstPage.routeName: (context) => const MyFirstPage(),
        MySecondPage.routeName: (context) => const MySecondPage(),
        MyThirdPage.routeName: (context) => const MyThirdPage(),
        MyFourthPage.routeName: (context) => const MyFourthPage(),
        MyFifthPage.routeName: (context) => const MyFifthPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class MyFirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  //final String title;

  static const routeName = '/';

  //const MyFirstPage({super.key, required this.title});
  const MyFirstPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyFirstPage> createState() => _MyFirstPageState();
}

class _MyFirstPageState extends State<MyFirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title;
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as FirstPageArguments;
    if (args == null) {
      title = 'Page 1';
    } else {
      title = args.title;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
              child: Text(
                'Flutter Named Routes',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 2 BUTTON - navigate to page 2 widget
            //
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String title = 'Page 2';
                String message = 'Welcome to page 2.';
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  MySecondPage.routeName,
                  arguments: SecondPageArguments(
                    title,
                    message,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Page 2'),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 3 BUTTON - navigate to page 3 widget
            //
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String title = 'Page 3';
                String message = 'Welcome to page 3.';
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  MyThirdPage.routeName,
                  arguments: ThirdPageArguments(
                    title,
                    message,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Page 3'),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 4 BUTOON - navigate to page 4 widget
            //
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String title = 'Page 4';
                bool status = true;
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  MyFourthPage.routeName,
                  arguments: FourthPageArguments(title, status),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Page 4'),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 5 BUTOON - navigate to page 5 widget
            //
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String title = 'Page 5';
                String message = 'Welcome to page 5.';
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  MyFifthPage.routeName,
                  arguments: FifthPageArguments(title, message),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Page 5'),
            ),
            // SizedBox(
            //   Text(args.message);
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**MySecondPage()**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'main.dart';

class MySecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySecondPage({super.key});

  static const routeName = '/secondPage';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Extract the arguments from the current ModalRoute
    // settings and cast them as SecondPageArguments
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as SecondPageArguments;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(args.title),
      ),
      // body: Center(
      //   child: Text(args.message),
      // ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
              child: Text(args.message, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String title = 'Page 1';
                String message = 'Returning from second page.';
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  MyFirstPage.routeName,
                  arguments: FirstPageArguments(
                    title,
                    message,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Return'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPageArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  SecondPageArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

I suspect there is a problem here:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
      ),
      //home: const MyFirstPage(title: 'Named Routes'),
      //initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        // register the page widgets in the routes table
        MyFirstPage.routeName: (context) => const MyFirstPage(),
        MySecondPage.routeName: (context) => const MySecondPage(),
        MyThirdPage.routeName: (context) => const MyThirdPage(),
        MyFourthPage.routeName: (context) => const MyFourthPage(),
        MyFifthPage.routeName: (context) => const MyFifthPage(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I have attempted to comment out `home:` and `initialRoute:` so I can register:

```
MyFirstPage.routeName: (context) => const MyFirstPage(),
```

`MyFirstPage()` widget in the `routes:` table. Frankly, I'm not sure how to handle this part.

Can someone please show me the correct way to route the user back from `MySecondPage()` to `MyFirstPage()` with the attributes shown here using `ModalRoute.of()`?

Answer (score 0):

After some additional troubleshooting, I was able to verify that the source of error is indeed related to the initialization of the variables in `FirstPageArguments()`.

```
class FirstPageArguments {
  final String title;
  final String message;

  FirstPageArguments(this.title, this.message);
}
```

`FirstPageArguments()` is initially null, but it is structured to not be nullable. To fix this problem, I made `FirstPageArguments()` nullable:

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as FirstPageArguments?;
```

This allows me to write a simple conditional to test `args` to see if it's null.

```
if (args == null) {
      title = 'Page 1';
      message = '';
    } else {
      title = args.title;
      message = args.message;
    }
```

In the case where `args` is null, I simply assign initialization values to `title` and `message`.

Thus, `MyFirstPage()` now becomes:

```
class MyFirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/';

  const MyFirstPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyFirstPage> createState() => _MyFirstPageState();
}

class _MyFirstPageState extends State<MyFirstPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String title;
    String message;
    final args =
        ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as FirstPageArguments?;
    // handle the case where title and message are initially null due to
    // ModalRoute not yet being called (make FirstPageArguments nullable above)
    // NOTE: this only affects MyFirstPage().
    if (args == null) {
      title = 'Page 1';
      message = '';
    } else {
      title = args.title;
      message = args.message;
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: const Text(
                'Flutter Named Routes',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 2 BUTTON - navigate to page 2 widget
            //
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  String title = 'Page 2';
                  String message = 'Welcome to Page 2';
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    MySecondPage.routeName,
                    arguments: SecondPageArguments(
                      title,
                      message,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Page 2'),
              ),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 3 BUTTON - navigate to page 3 widget
            //
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  String title = 'Page 3';
                  String message = 'Welcome to Page 3';
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    MyThirdPage.routeName,
                    arguments: ThirdPageArguments(
                      title,
                      message,
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Page 3'),
              ),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 4 BUTOON - navigate to page 4 widget
            //
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  String title = 'Page 4';
                  bool status = true;
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    MyFourthPage.routeName,
                    arguments: FourthPageArguments(title, status),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Page 4'),
              ),
            ),
            //
            // PAGE 5 BUTOON - navigate to page 5 widget
            //
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  String title = 'Page 5';
                  String message = 'Welcome to Page 5';
                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                    context,
                    MyFifthPage.routeName,
                    arguments: FifthPageArguments(title, message),
                  );
                },
                child: const Text('Page 5'),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                message,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

The button that returns the user to `MyFirstPage()` is written this way:

```
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String title = 'Page 1';
                String message = 'Returning from second page.';
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  MyFirstPage.routeName,
                  arguments: FirstPageArguments(
                    title,
                    message,
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Return'),
            ),
```

The entire app is available [here](https://github.com/robfrei/named_routes).